# Pythonでnumpy.ndarrayからPIL.Imageに変換がうまく行かない

Tags: python, numpy, pillow

Pythonのnumpy配列で作成した2値配列をPIL.Imageに変換して扱いたいと考えているのですが、その変換が意図通りに行かず苦戦しております。
以下が簡易化したサンプルコードになります。

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([
  [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
  [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
  [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
], dtype=np.uint8) * 255

print(arr)

img = Image.fromarray(arr, "1")

print(np.asarray(img))
img.save("result.png")
```

実行結果は以下です。

```
[[  0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]]
[[False False False False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]]
```

出力された画像は以下
[image: result.png]

斜めに縞が入ったような画像が得られることを期待していましたが、横に不揃いな線が入った画像になってしまいます。
どこを間違えているのかご教示お願いいたします。

Pythonのバージョンは 3.7.3
numpyのバージョンは 1.16.2
Pillowのバージョンは 5.4.1 です。

Comment: 画像データが簡単なら、まず有効な画像データを作ってnumpyやPILで読み込んで内容を調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [Chainer v4 PILからNumpy NumpyからPILの変換](https://qiita.com/DogFortune/items/b6e71ba8aa5b358f01af), [Python, NumPyで画像処理（読み込み、演算、保存）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-image-processing/), [Python, OpenCVで画像ファイルの読み込み、保存（imread, imwrite）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-imread-imwrite/)

Comment: `Image.fromarray(arr, "1")` で `"1"` を指定していますが、これでは 1-bit pixel での指定になりますので、この場合は `"L"`(8-bit pixel) を指定すべきかと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> img = Image.fromarray(arr, "1")

第2匹数の"1"を消したらおそらく質問者様が
想定されている挙動を確認できました。

下記記事にmode=1に関して挙動が怪しい
(バグの可能性もあり)との記述も見られるので
mode=Lを使うのが良さそうな感じもしますね

https://koji.noshita.net/post/2017/0224-pillow/

Comment: 第2引数の省略で期待通りの結果が得られることを確認できました。
一応後続の処理で2値画像である必要があったため以下のように修正しました。
第2引数のmode指定は変換の意味を含んでいないんですかね。
ひとまず解決しました、ありがとうございます。

img = Image.fromarray(arr).convert("1")